Angular ngStyle directive not working: style properties don't update
I'm trying to use the [ngStyle] directive in an Angular 17 app to dynamically show or hide an element, like this:
<div [ngStyle]="{visibility: loaded ? 'collapse' : 'visible' }">
    ...
</div>

where loaded is a boolean property in my component.
The problem is: this doesn't work. It correctly sets the visibility property at the start according to the initial value of loaded, but after that if I at some point change the value of loaded the visibility doesn't change accordingly. Am I missing something basic here? I've also tried with [style] instead of [ngStyle] but the result is exactly the same.
Edit: here's my imports in the component:
imports: [
    NgIf,
    ProgressBarModule,
    NgStyle,
    CommonModule
  ],

EDIT 2: after further testing, it seems that Angular is not detecting the change in the loaded property for some reason.
If I inject ChangeDetectorRef into the component and manually trigger change detection, like this:
this.loaded = true;
this.cdRef.detectChanges();

it start working correctly.
Note that the code that flips the loaded property is inside a Promise... can that be the issue? Are changes made inside a Promise block not auto-detected by Angular in general?

UPDATE:
You have OnPush Change detection strategy enabled.
This triggers change detection only when @Inputs of a component or browser/user events (button click)
Read about it in details on the angular docs
That is why the asynchronous call is not updating the UI and you have to do this.cdRef.detectChanges();

Make sure you imported either CommonModule or NgStyle directive into the component only then will the directive work.
CommonModule contains the directives needed for using NgStyle or NgClass.
...
@Component({
     selector: '...',
     standalone: true,
     imports: [CommonModule],
    ...
})
export class SomeComponent {
    ...


If it's standalone -> the imports should be in the imports array of the component.
If it's modular -> go to the module, where the component is added to the declarations array and add the import.


I've checked my imports, but they look ok (see edited question)

@Master_T issue not reproducible stackblitz

I've tried with hidden, but same result. And I tested 'collapse' on its own (without ngStyle, just via CSS) and it works correctly even on divs, so the problem is somewhere else...

@Master_T Please replicate in stackblitz, else do an inspect element and check which CSS is interfering

thanks for your replies, I've edited the question once again. It seems the problem is not with CSS but with Angular change detection.

@Master_T updated my answer with the explanation, maybe turn off on push change detection
